# Adding a component to Deployed application ATG

Tags: atg

Trying to find out how can we attach a component to a deployed application in ATG.I have MotorpriseJSP demo ATG application deployed in my JBOSS and have created a component named Person in my ATG using control center.
I am not sure how i can attach this Person component to the MotorpriseJSP application deployed in JBOSS so that i can see the code in action.'

any help in this regard will be much appriciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have compiled the class and made it part of the assembled EAR file and included the property file that makes Person a Nucleus component, you can either

a) connect ACC to the running instance and start the component manually

b) reference the component in /dyn/admin (try localhost:8080/dyn/admin/NUCLEUS-PATH-OF-PERSON
- that will instantiate it.

That is to instantiate the component inside running Motorprise. You can also refer the component from other running Nucleus component (a.g. add it to Initial.properties) but that will require restart or re-assembly of the MotorpriseJSP